# Automatic Facebook Bot Creation and Approval

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've noticed services such as motion.ai and manychat.com are able to automatically create Facebook messenger bots for users. These bots are instantly approved for public access and subscription messaging. How is it possible that companies/services are able to bypass the Facebook approval process for bots?

Comment: They don't, they just use their already approved bot on multiple pages.

Comment: There's no way that's what they are doing, it's not scalable.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: So you are saying that every bot created on motion.io for example, is going through one single Facebook app? There's thousands of pages flowing through a single webhook?

Comment: Why not? Facebook doesn't care if they have to send one request each to a thousand different registered webhook URLs, or a thousand requests to one single URL. And handling that amount of data on the other end, at motion.io's side, is no problem either - "the cloud" can handle that.

Comment: And Facebook has no limit on how many pages can subscribe to a bot? It's unlimited?

Comment: Dunno if it is actually "unlimited", Facebook does not usually document such limits. But it's gonna be more than just a handful, that's for sure.